# Nuxtjs 3 and nested routes

Tags: nuxt.js, router, nuxt3

I have a page with an unknown number of parameters like :
mysite.com/wiki/a/b/c/d/e/f

I want all routes that start with /wiki to direct to wiki.vue page

This page parses the full url and displays appropriate content

I'm struggling to accomplish that with Nuxt 3 and not finding any information.

Comment: I think you could handle this with https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages/#catch-all-route. Alternatively your could add a client side middleware and catch the page if to.path startsWith('/wiki')

I used it for server - there is also this awesome functionality